# tokenize the url

Tags: python, tokenize

I have a sentences (logs) look like that `['GET http://10.0.0.0:1000/ HTTP/X.X']`
I want to have it in this form :

```
['GET', 'http://10.0.0.0:1000/', 'HTTP/X.X']
```

but that's not the fall. i've used this code :

```
import re

sentences = ['GET http://10.0.0.0:1000/ HTTP/X.X']
rx = re.compile(r'\b(\w{3})\s+(\d{1,2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\w+)\W+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?:\s+\S+){2}\s+\[([^][\s]+)\s+([+\d]+)]\s+"([A-Z]+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)"\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+\S+\s+"([^"]*)')

words=[]
for sent in sentences:
    m = rx.search(sent)
    if m:
        words.append(list(m.groups()))
    else:
        words.append(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))  

print(words)
```

i get as an output :

```
[['GET', 'http', ':', '//10.0.0.0:1000/', 'HTTP/X.X']]
```

can someone know where is the error, or why it's not working as i want .
Thank you

Comment: Split on a space?

Comment: Does the URL ever contain (unescaped) whitespace literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

sentences = ['GET http://10.0.0.0:1000/ HTTP/X.X']

words=[]

for sent in sentences:
    words.append(list(sent.split(' ')))

print(words)
```

Can you use a simple space split? I think nltk.word_tokenize is given you the wrong output!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you want to split it using a space. So,

```
sentences = ['GET http://10.0.0.0:1000/ HTTP/X.X']
words = [x.split(" ") for x in sentences]
print(words)
```